# Rsync Local to Remote - Stating both source and destination are remote

Tags: server, ssh, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to transfer files from my local windows machine to a remote ubuntu machine.

I have searched online and have had no dice.

When I try to run the command, rsync tells me that the source and destination both cannot be remote. I am trying to transfer from local to remote, so I am unsure why this is happening.

My command is:

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing -e 'ssh -p 2023' root@remoteip:/remote/file/path C:\Users\local\file\path
```

Comment: What do you mean "Windows"? Are you using WSL (Linux on Windows) or the windows command line? Why are you using Windows style paths? And what do you want to copy where? Your command is attempting to copy `/remote/file/path` to `C:\Users\local\file\path`, don't you want the inverse?

Comment: My guess is that `rsync` tells you that both paths are remote because of colon in the second path (after `C`). You need to explain more detailed where are you running this command, and if this is on Windows command line, what implementation of `rsync` are you using - because `rsync` is not natively built into Windows.